# How to use editable dynamic Dropdown-list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an VBA-Code right now, which should:

- let you select a text from a dropdown-list
- select multiple text and put it on the next line
- let you edit the values of the cell.
  The Problem here is that when I disable the Error message - so I can edit the cell, the values from the target cell get added to the cell.

So for example I want to edit B to C in the Dropdown cell. 
Instead I get A B A C

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngDV As Range
Dim wert_old As String
Dim wertnew As String

On Error GoTo Errorhandling

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A6")) Is Nothing Then


  Set rngDV = Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
  If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo Errorhandling

  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    wertnew = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    wertold = Target.Value
    Target.Value = wertnew
    If wertold <> "" Then
      If wertnew <> "" Then
        Target.Value = wertold & vbCrLf & wertnew
      End If
    End If
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

Errorhandling:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The probelem here is that selecting a value from dropdown and editing the cell manually fires the same event `Worksheet_Change`. Therefore the 2 actions cannot be distinguished and therefore they act the same. So you probably cannot solve this.

Comment: Yes I get the Problem, could it be done with another Code ?

Comment: You might want to seperate the actions "dropdown selected" and "cell edited" manually inside the "Worksheet_Change" event (e.g. by saving the relevant cells to another place and compare them). Your code sample above is not complete to reproduce your issue.    Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must use `vbLf` as linebreak in cells instead of `vbCrLf`
2. Use `Option Explicit` to prevent using wrong variable names. You declared `wert_old` but you used `wertold`. This will easily mess up and drive you nuts. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.
3. As a workaround you can run your code only if it doesn't contain a `vbLf` by using
   `InStr(1, Target.Value, vbLf) < 1`

   Note that this workaround will make you able to edit the cell if there is more than one item in it but if you try to edit if it only contains one item it will still add it (I have no workaround for that).

So you end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Errorhandling

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A6")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim rngDV As Range
        Set rngDV = Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
        If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo Errorhandling

        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing And InStr(1, Target.Value, vbLf) < 1 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False

            Dim WertNew As String
            WertNew = Target.Value

            Application.Undo

            Dim WertOld As String
            WertOld = Target.Value
            Target.Value = WertNew
            If WertOld <> vbNullString Then
                If WertNew <> vbNullString Then
                    Target.Value = WertOld & vbLf & WertNew
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

Errorhandling:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort! But now I cant choose multiple values in my dropdownlist.

Comment: @kevin_23 are you sure you used exactly this code? I tested it. See the screenshot in my answer. • Run `Application.EnableEvents = True` once to make sure events are enabled.

Comment: Really funny, i changed the values and it works now! Thank you so much!